# Mathematical resource material accompanying TAPL

Tags: computability, programming-languages, type-theory, mathematical-foundations, types-and-programming-languages

I'm currently reading *Types and Programming Languages* by Benjamin C. Pierce and just arrived at chapter 21 *Metatheory of Recursive Types*.

Prior to this chapter I found the book challenging but comprehensible, but I'm lost on this chapter. Almost none of the definition make intuitively sense to me. Are there any more accessible resources regarding the principle of (co-)induction, tree types and least and greatest fixed points as defined in chapter 21?

Comment: I agree the presentation is quite involved. I did my way to coinduction through the theory of coalgebras. However, I'm not aware of better references for this setting